# Blender 2.8 bake node displacement as UV

Tags: uv, node-editor, baking

[image]

How is it possible to bake?
Or is it possible to change the object?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of using Displacement in Material Output node is through Displacement node (Vector->Displacement) and connecting image to the Height input. But even that way I believe Displacement in node editor doesn't work in Eevee, only in Cycles in rendered view. In Eevee it only shows up as bump. The only way to get Displacement in Eevee is by using Displace modifier.

Clarifications for baking color:
[image]

Then you click New on Image Texture to create new texture. Switch Render Engine to Cycles, set options for baking color:

[image]

Click Bake, wait to complete, then get to image editor where you select your image from dropdown at the top and save it as (Shift+S).

Comment: It's not wrong to use, just the end result is not a displacement, but bump. Displacement is actual deformation of the mesh, bump is just distortion of mesh normals. If you look at an angle on your mesh it's still flat. If you are just using magic texture you can just bake color from it to new texture. Connect your magic texture to Color Ramp and then to color input of Principled BSDF node, create new image texture (select its node in node editor), switch to Cycles, switch bake type to Diffuse, select under Diffuse to bake only color and click bake. Look up baking tutorials for clarification.